# Recursion function to find highest value returns 0s

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

```
#find highest number

def HighValue(arr, HighestValue=0):
    if len(arr) > 0:
        arrayValue = arr.pop()
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return HighestValue
    elif HighestValue <= arrayValue:
        HighestValue = arrayValue
        return HighValue(arr, HighestValue)
    else:
        return HighValue(arr, HighestValue)

print HighValue([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

This function returns the highest value of an array using recursion. It works, but I feel like I am writing more code than necessary. Does anyone have any advice as to whether I could have made this recursion algorithm simpler? I hope I am allowed to ask quesitons like that here. If not, let me know. I feel I will get better if I get feedback from more experienced programers.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: If this is **working code** you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. Or just use `max`.

Comment: I think you should use `max`.

Comment: Want you use recursion just for study?

Comment: Using `pop()` is a bad idea since it destructively mutates the list in the process of finding its max. Losing all of your data is a high price to pay when all you want to do is find the largest datum.

Comment: When you pass a one-element array as the argument, you never look at the value you pop before you return the value of `HighestValue`.

Comment: Note that the code above does not work correctly - if the largest element is first, the answer is wrong.  @Prune has a good (and correct) example of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are some programming design basics involved, I'll answer this instead of remanding it to CodeReview.

Yes, you're writing more code than needed.  You don't need to force all of the mechanics yourself.  Worry about the base case, the recursion step, and the return value.  Everything else should be easy from there.

- Don't pass the best value through the parameter list; just pass back the best value you have so far.
- Don't pop things off the list; just call the routine with the tail of the list.  Note that my solution strips elements off the beginning, instead of the end.  You are welcome to reverse this logic.

If the list is only one element long, return it.  When you get back to the parent call, return the higher of the end element or the returned value:

```
def HighValue(arr):
    best = 0
    if len(arr) > 0:
        best = HighestValue(arr[1:])
    return best if best > arr[0] else arr[0]
```

If you're not worried about execution time, you can elide **best** with an extra recursive call.

Comment: When I use your code it says, Index Error: list index out of range?

Comment: Ah nvm that seemed to work. I corrected the HighestValue(arr[1:]) to HighValue(arr[1:]) and it seems to work great. In my tests I noticed that the best = 0 seemed to make no difference on how the script executed so I removed that too and it seems to work great. Thanks for your insight. I am starting to understand recursion much better now.

Comment: Excellent!  You do need **best** to have a value for the comparison, or in case the original input list is empty.

Comment: Ah ok, I never tested an empty list. That being said, I find that bizarre that it is needed for the comparison if the list is not empty because I set the value of best to ridiculously high values and that changed nothing on the outcome of the function.... I put 100000 as the value for best and the highest value in my list was 5000. It still returned 5000 as anticipated. This leaves me a little bit confused as logically, I agree with you, I just dont understand why the program is functioning in that way.